# Split an array of hashes in an array into slices

Tags: ruby

Lets say you have a string

```
initial_message = "My dear cousin bill!"
```

I put this string of N characters in an array of hashes (where each letter is the key and the value is A = 0 , B = 1, C = 2.. etc).

```
hsh_letter_values = Hash[('a'..'z').zip (0..25).to_a] #Map letters to numbers in a hash
clean_message = initial_message.tr('^a-zA-Z0-9','').downcase #remove non-letters
char_map = clean_message.each_char.map { |i| { i => hsh_letter_values[i] } } #map each letter of message to corresponding number
```

Then I split the char_map into slices of 16.

```
char_split_map = char_map.each_slice(16).to_a
```

I want to split each 16 character slice into slices of 4, while keeping the hashes in the same order.

The outcome should look like:

```
[[[{"m"=>12}, {"y"=>24}, {"d"=>3}, {"e"=>4}],[{"a"=>0}, {"r"=>17}, {"c"=>2}, {"o"=>14}], [{"u"=>20}, {"s"=>18}, {"i"=>8}, {"n"=>13}], [{"b"=>1}, {"i"=>8}, {"l"=>11}, {"l"=>11}]]
```

I am planning on adding the values of each letter from each column to get four sums (C1,C2,C3,C4)
So for the first column it would be 12+0+20+1.

This is what I have so far `http://repl.it/2cd/1`.

Any help on what im doing wrong or a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: What is your question? You have working code that produces the array `[[[{"m"=>12},...`.  Are you asking if that code can be improved? If so, that should be asked on Code Review, not SO. If you are not asking how to improve that code, get rid of it and start the question with that array.  You then say, "I am planning...". If that is your question, say so: "I would like to know how I can...".  It's good to present what you've tried so far, but that should be part of your question, not at a link, as links can be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, starting with the message:

```
msg = "My dear cousin bill!"

arr = msg.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/,'').chars.each_slice(4).to_a
  #=> [["m", "y", "d", "e"],
  #    ["a", "r", "c", "o"],
  #    ["u", "s", "i", "n"],
  #    ["b", "i", "l", "l"]]

4.times.map { |i| arr.reduce(0) { |t,a| t + (a[i]||?a).ord-?a.ord } }
  #=> [33, 67, 24, 42]

msg = "My dearest cousin bill!"

arr = msg.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/,'').chars.each_slice(4).to_a
  #=> [["m", "y", "d", "e"],
  #    ["a", "r", "e", "s"],
  #    ["t", "c", "o", "u"],
  #    ["s", "i", "n", "b"],
  #    ["i", "l", "l"]]

4.times.map { |i| arr.reduce(0) { |t,a| t + (a[i]||?a).ord-?a.ord } }
  #=>[57, 62, 45, 43]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with a slightly different approach:

```
initial_message = "My dear cousin bill!"
chars = initial_message.tr('^a-zA-Z0-9','').downcase.chars
char_map = ->(char) { char.ord - 97 }

results = chars.each_slice(4).each_slice(4).map do |array| 
  array.transpose.map {|column| column.reduce(0) {|res, letter| res + char_map[letter]} }
end

results.inspect     => '[[33, 67, 24, 42]]'
```

This is not hitting the intermediate step you described in your question, however is probably a better way to achieve your final result.

Comment: There's a problem using `transpose` if the number of characters after stripping is not mod 4: `"My dearest cousin bill!" => [[49, 51, 34, 43], [8, 11, 11]]`. You could pad the end with `'a'`'s, but that's a bit clunky.